# How to horizontally center align a span inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV and a SPAN. I would like to center the SPAN horizontally inside the DIV.

I am trying to center that inside the headerRibbon div but no matter what code I use, it's not working.

I am loading the mobile stylesheet shown above like this:

```
<!-- default stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/defaultStyle.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/captionStyle.css" />

<!-- mobile stylesheets
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/defaultStyle_mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (min-device-width : 320px)" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/captionStyle_mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (min-device-width : 320px)" />-->

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="theStyles/defaultStyle_mobile.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="theStyles/captionStyle_mobile.css" />

<!-- if ie version 9 or less -->

<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/defaultStyle_ie.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/captionStyle_ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

The `div` is displayed as `block` once it slides down on page load:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried making the span display: inline-block; then making the div text-align: center; ?

Comment: Why is `socialIcons` set to `display: table` and then also contains a table?

Comment: well, it works for me(http://jsfiddle.net/86s8C/). I guess your problem is somewhere else in your code..

Comment: it is already centered.. http://jsfiddle.net/2b6Hq/

maybe something else is interfering

Comment: I am using conditional statement to load different stylesheet so the wrong one should not be loading :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to make the span `display: inline-block;` and make the div `text-align: center;` or make the span `display: inline-block;` and `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: Nope... not working. I wonder if the table is somehow interfering with anything :/

Comment: I saw a lot of examples but still mines not working. I will take a look further into detail. Thanks.,

Comment: Another solution that I might not prefer is to set the DIV to position: relative; and the span to position: absolute; then transform: translate(-50%, 0); and finally left: 50%.. like in here http://jsfiddle.net/3JE3G/2/

Comment: your solution works except now the top is blocked off by the background wallpaper :/

Comment: I removed the `position: relative;` from the `div` itself and everything is working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto;` is likely what you are looking for.

Comment: When the headerRibbon is displayed using jQuery on page load, the display is block. Maybe that's why it's causing an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#textSearch {
    display: none;
}
#imageSearch {
    display: none;
}
#extraLinks {
    display: none;
}
#socialIcons {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-left:25%;
}
#headerRibbon {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.socialIconTD {
    margin:0 10%;
    width:1%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="headerRibbon">
    <span id="socialIcons">
        <table cellpadding=0>
            <tr>
                <td class="socialIconTD"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/test"><img alt="" title="" src="theImages/facebook_bw.png" class="fbClass" id="fb" width="25" height="25" /></a></td>
                <td class="socialIconTD"><a href="http://twitter.com/WEST"><img alt="" title="" src="theImages/twitter_bw.png" class="twClass" id="tw" width="25" height="25" /></a></td>
                <td class="socialIconTD"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/65676575676?trk=tyah"><img alt="" title="" src="theImages/linkedin_bw.png" class="liClass" id="li" width="25" height="25" /></a></td>
                <td class="socialIconTD"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/WEST?blend=3&ob=5"><img alt="" title="" src="theImages/youtube_bw.png" class="ytClass" id="yt" width="25" height="25" /></a></td>
                <td class="socialIconTD"><a href="http://pinterest.com/wesT/"><img alt="" title="" src="theImages/pinterest_bw.png" class="ptClass" id="pt" width="25" height="25" /></a></td>
                <td class="socialIconTD"><a href="https://plus.google.com/112233755586149090-9-90-7"><img alt="" title="" src="theImages/googleplus_bw.png" class="gpClass" id="gp" width="25" height="25" /></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </span>
    <input type="text" size="30" placeholder="Searc" id="textSearch" /><img alt="Search Within" title="Search Within" src="theImages/blue_blur.png" width="22" height="22" id="imageSearch" class="imageSearch" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the images evenly spaced?

Comment: If so, I have your fix. I got it to work but you'll have to change the width from 1% (i don't have the image files) to whatever you wanted them to be.

Comment: @SiKni8 I changed your socialIconTD's to a class instead of id's. Also, you will have to adjust the width of the socialIconTD class because I didn't have the image files, so I had to give them a width.

Comment: Because I have two separate stylesheets, do you think the default stylesheet could be interfering with the mobile one? After all, I am testing them here: http://www.responsinator.com/. Their size is 25X25px

Comment: That is SO weird. Something else is messing with the styles. not working at all! :/

Comment: When the `headerRibbon` is displayed using jQuery on page load, the display is `block`. Maybe that's why it's causing an issue?

Comment: @Mohammed R. El-Khoudi's solution works except now the headerRibbon doesn't have a background the image gets cut off